# bash defined array and compare input to stored array value

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a all=("a" "b" "c")

echo -n  "Please enter one value ${all[@]} [ENTER]: "
read site
echo "You entered $site as site"
read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm && [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1


for item in "${all[@]}"; do
echo $item
 if [[ "${site}" == "${all[@]}" ]]; then
  echo "Site Name validated"
 else
  echo "No Match For Site Name" && exit 1
 fi
done
```

In the input even if type a, b or c. I am not able to validate input against defined array, not meeting if statement
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regex test like

```
[[ " ${all[@]} " =~ " $site " ]] && echo in || echo out
```

might be sufficient. You may want to protect against false positives, though.

And, the way you evaluate the confirmation, it will quit the script with an error exit code if you enter `y`, `Y`, or `yes` in any upper / lower case combination.

Answer (score 2):

(I’ll assume that you have changed `if [[ "${site}" == "${all[@]}" ]]` to `if [[ "$site" == "$item" ]]`.)

Just imagine how your loop executes. 
Suppose you type `b`. 
The first iteration of the loop sets `item` equal to `a`. 
You compare `b` to `a`. 
If they were equal, you would report validation. 
But they aren’t equal, so you report failure and exit.

It’s no better it you type `a`. 
On the first iteration of the loop,
`item` is `a` and you report success *and keep on looping*. 
Then `item` becomes `b`, and you go into the `else` clause,
where you report failure and exit.

The problem is that you report failure if the input
is different from any of the valid values. 
But *any* input will be different from at least two of the valid values
(invalid inputs will be different from all three). 
You need to report success if the input is equal to any of the valid values,
and failure otherwise.

Exactly how you do this depends on the big picture. 
If reading input and validating it is ***all*** that you want to do,
you need only a small rearrangement of your current code:

```
for item in "${all[@]}"; do
    echo "$item"
    if [[ "$site" == "$item" ]]; then
        echo "Site Name validated" && exit 0
    fi
done
echo "No Match For Site Name" && exit 1
```

But if (as is likely)
you want the script to go on and *do something* with valid input,
a good way is to use a flag:

```
valid=
for item in "${all[@]}"; do
    echo "$item"
    if [[ "$site" == "$item" ]]; then
        echo "Site Name validated" && valid=1
    fi
done
if ! [ "$valid" ]
then
    echo "No Match For Site Name" && exit 1
fi
# (script continues with valid input)
               ︙
```

P.S. You don’t need to say `"${site}"` in this context; `"$site"` is fine.

Comment: putting the test in a function would probably be a good idea too